# How to select particular key from database field?

Tags: mysql

[image: how to get value 6 existed in year_id 6 and make_id=1]

```
SELECT *
FROM manage_model
WHERE year_id IN(6)
AND make_id=1
```

I tried this code. It is not working.

Comment: what is the type of `year_id` column ?

Comment: year_id type is varchar 255

Comment: It is not working, because of your effed-up data model. Go read up on proper _normalization_. (FIND_IN_SET could be used here, but that would not fix the actual, underlying issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM manage_model where CONCAT(',',year_id,',') like '%,6,%' AND make_id=1
```

Comment: Be careful if `year_id` contains only 1 value. In that case, I think the value would not contain comma.

Comment: SELECT * FROM manage_model WHERE (year_id like ('%,6,%')) AND (make_id=1)

Comment: @HasifSaheb I have corrected the query, please check.

Comment: @HasifSaheb If this helps you, please mark it as answer.